# edit all environment variables- advance tab my computer- through QTP

Tags: qtp

is there any code in qtp that can go to my computer select properties, then go to advance tab, environment variables and can edit all the variables that already exist.

Regards,
Jitu

Comment: Have you tried and faces any problems? Is so please show what you did and what problems you ran into.

Answer (score 4):

Presumably your goal is not to test setting environment variables through Advanced tab, but to change them from a QTP script anyhow.

You can easily change them using VBscript capabilities. Look at these functions:

```
Public Function GetEnvVariable(ByVal strEnvVarName)
  Set oShell = CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
  GetEnvVariable = oShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings(strEnvVarName)
End Function

Public Function SetEnvVariable(ByVal strEnvVarName, ByVal strNewValue)
  Set oShell = CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
  oShell.Environment.item(strEnvVarName) = strNewValue
End Function
```

[Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable) you can read more about environment variables. Also [WshEnvironment Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6s7w15a0%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) may be useful for you.

Comment: +1 for answering the problem not the question. Although it could be that the OP is using QTP for automating stuff not for testing (some people use QTP for data injection).

Comment: OP? What does that stand for? Opponent? :)